# Class has more than one constructor

Tags: c++

Currently, im working on an CVector class, everything was working fine until i wanted to use vectors in other classes like `CVector v;` and use the `v` later.

well, the problem lies there - i would use

```
 struct Vector3_t {
    float x, y , z;

};
```

but i want to use operators for those vectors, so i made a class:

```
class CVector
{
public:

    //missing usage: CVector vec; // for later usage in example.
    CVector() // usage: CVector v();
    {
        this->x = 0, this->y = 0, this->z = 0;
    }

    CVector(const float x = 0, const float y = 0) { // usage: CVector v(1,2); // but z is always 0 
        this->x = x, this->y = y,this->z = 0;
    }

    CVector(const float x = 0, const float y = 0, const float z = 0) {  // usage: CVector v(1,2,3);
        this->x = x, this->y = y, this->z = z;
    }

    CVector & CVector::operator += (const CVector & v) {
        this->x += v.x; this->y += v.y; this->z += v.z; return *this;
    }
    const CVector CVector::operator + (const CVector& v) const {
        CVector r(*this); return r += v;
    }

    float x, y, z;
    ~CVector() {};
protected:

private:
};
```

in action:

```
int main() {

    CVector vec; 
    return 0;
}
```

**output errors:**
*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      class "CVector" has more than one default constructor   mebad   c:\Users\lifesucks\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mebad\mebad\main.cpp   43*

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2668   'CVector::CVector': ambiguous call to overloaded function   mebad   c:\users\lifesucks\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\mebad\mebad\main.cpp   43
*

basically i just have no idea how to declare class for this kind of use when having multiple constructors, and i dont want to use more function like CVector::constr1 which would use 3 floats or anything similiar, there must be a way to do it this way, could i get a bit of help? Thanks!

Comment: _"but i want to use operators for those vectors, so i made a class"_, `struct`s can have operator overloads too.

Comment: @Grantly shouldnt be there, i was just trying to show u i tried different ways but didnt find it out, give me sec i will edit it to not mistake u
-zenith and if i wanted to use it this way with class, could i get a help? It quite interests me i wouldn't ask otherwise.

Comment: When posting questions about code that gives you errors, include *all* of the output in the question body, complete and unedited.

Comment: You could have removed all but one constructor, get it working, then add another constructor...Then the answer below would become apparent :)  Welcome to Stack Overflow, have a good day!

Comment: You can keep your variable declaration CVector *vec = new CVector(); - but you still have constructors that look the same to the compiler as the arguments are optional.  remove the '=0' from the constructors...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your use of default values for the arguments to two of the constructors, that means you have three constructors that can be called without arguments, so which should the compiler call?

Simply remove the default argument values and it should work.

Comment: Or better, remove all but the three-argument constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by argument values? You want me to remove constructors or `this->x = 0` etc?

Comment: Argument VALUES are the "= 0", etc in your function definition.

Comment: @dadasdasdas No, in the arguments to the constructor you have e.g. `const float x = 0`, the `= 0` is the parts that causes you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be

```
class CVector
{
public:
    CVector() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
    CVector(float x) : x(x), y(0), z(0) {}
    CVector(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y), z(0) {}
    CVector(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    //...

    float x, y, z;
};
```

or

```
class CVector
{
public:
    CVector(float x = 0, float y = 0, float z = 0) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    //...

    float x, y, z;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Joachim Pileborg answered this perfectly, and deserves the points.

Here are the code changes you chould make:

```
CVector() // usage: CVector v();
{
    this->x = 0, this->y = 0, this->z = 0;
}

CVector(const float x, const float y) { // usage: CVector v(1,2); // but z is always 0 
    this->x = x, this->y = y,this->z = 0;
}

CVector(const float x, const float y, const float z) {  // usage: CVector v(1,2,3);
    this->x = x, this->y = y, this->z = z;
}
```